# 90s (or earlier) sci-fi novel about astronauts time traveling to a post-apocalyptic France where people are afraid of the time of Christmas

Tags: story-identification, novel

A group of astronauts come back to Earth and have time traveled to a post-apocalyptic France they initially think is the past. They eventually join a clan of people who are afraid of the time of Noël (Christmas). One of them breaks his leg and has to design primitive crutches.

I read an English-language copy of this book in the late 90s.

Comment: Hi, Kelly. You're on to a nice start, but some more detail would be nice: When did you read this novel? Was it old at the time? Did you read it in French or English or some other language? Why was the clan afraid of Noël? Can you remember any other details that might help people recognize the book?

Comment: I read an English language copy of this book in the late 90s.

Comment: Cool, I'll edit it into the question.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly *The Quiet Place* (1987) by Richard Maynard, also known as *The Return*.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4098186-the-quiet-place):

> Seven British astronauts embark on a three-year, long-range mission into space. Something goes wrong and they are lost for 16 years. Upon return to earth they discover that, back home, several hundred years have elapsed. Earth is not as they left it: civilization is gone and mankind has reverted to a 'caveman-like' state. What happened to society?

At least part of the action is set in France, according to [this review](http://theporporbooksblog.blogspot.com/2011/04/book-review-return-by-richard-maynard-4.html):

> When the ship reaches Earth orbit, there is a disturbing absence of radio communications. The crew proceeds with splashdown into the Atlantic and find that no ships or aircraft have come to greet them. **They inflate their emergency life-raft and slowly make for the coast of France. Upon arrival they are stunned to discover that the countryside is devoid of lights and traffic;** everywhere the landscape is covered with bushes and trees, suggesting that civilization as they know it has ceased to exist.

And [this Abebooks description](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:oaiGUGcf1MQJ:https://www.abebooks.com/9780586208083/Quiet-Place-Maynard-Richard-0586208089/) (cached) mentions Christmas, without saying whether folks are afraid of it, but it's possible:

> Several astronauts return to Earth after what they believe is sixty years of Earth time. But a distortion of the spacetime continuum means that they arrive back centuries after they set off. **They discover a Europe inhabited by savage hunting tribes whose only link with the culture of "modern" man is a crude version of former language and the vague memory of "Nowell time" or Christmas.** It is a world where civilization has been abandoned and forgotten centuries before - where humanity's achievements have become a scrap of unrecorded history, meaningless and lost for all time. But what has happened to make mankind reject its previously advanced civilization?

---

Found with the Google query `science fiction book astronauts time travel post apocalyptic france site:goodreads.com/book` which brought up the linked Goodreads page.